# Time Frame to perform Homam

Tags: puranas, rituals, customs

If there is a death in the house [especially parents] what is the time frame to conduct Homam? Should it be performed after Varushapdhigam  [after one year of ceremony]? 
Albeit I am doing homams this answer I do not know. Kindly quote from  puranas or bhagavathams where the solution exists.
This question is not for debate, discussion or arguments.

Comment: I think there is only one bhagwatam , the period of not doing any homa would be the sutaka period or asucha period it generally lasts for 10 days in case of a relative and 13-15 days in case of close relatives. Btw doing Agnihotra is allowed if you are trained into it and wear a yajnopavita.

Comment: The answer is vague. I came to know from a friend who is a non Brahmin and his father expired. For the next one year they will not do any homams. The theetu is for 12 days and 13th day subham is conducted and will be visiting temples. After that for next one year we should not go to temple as per sastras.

Comment: Well its not an answer its a comment, still I can quote some scriptures to support my comment.

Comment: please comment from scriptures